# Percent sign in URL without hyperref

Tags: urls, editors, texworks, comments

Suppose you want to create a URL that has embedded % signs.  One option is to just use `\%`, but you don't get the benefit of nice line breaks.  Another option is to use the `hyperref` package and its `\url` command.  There is no need to escape the % sign then, but you might as well, since most editors will get the syntax highlighting wrong otherwise.  But suppose you don't want `hyperref`.  There's also the `url` package which just gives nice line breaks but no links.  Unfortunately, trying to use `\%` with this package actually typesets it literally as `\%`, instead of escaping the % sign.  Is there anything that can be done about this?  (Simplifying assumption, if it helps: I have no intention of typesetting a url that contains an embedded `\` within this document.)  I suppose I should provide a MWE example, though it seems superfluous here:

```
\documentclass{article}
  \usepackage{url}
  \begin{document}
    \url{\%}
   \end{document}
```

Comment: The main purpose of using the `\url` macro of the eponymous package is to typeset URL strings that may contain (nearly) arbitrary characters. If you're going to use the `url` package, why would you even consider escaping "special" characters (such as `%`) in the first place?

Comment: My editor's syntax highlighting gets confused otherwise.

Comment: Which editor do you use? Is there a way to turn off syntax checking inside the argument of `\url`? Clearly, no syntax checking should be going on in there.

Comment: I use TexWorks.

Comment: I've taken the liberty of adding the tag 'texworks' to your posting.

Comment: Ok, this might be a texworks question at heart.  But the fact remains that hyperref gets this "right" for the value of "right" I care about, and it uses the url package internally.  (Or does it?  I know it loads it.)  And the manual for the url package has some scary looking sections that talk about customization, so I suspect this is possible.  It's just a question of finding the right incantation.

Comment: @jak123 -- Why did you delete the 'texworks' tag? Please explain.

Comment: probably because there is no mention of TeXworks in my question, and it is likely that many editors have this problem.

Comment: @Mark: So you issue here is with using `%` as-is in a URL and that screws up your editor?

Comment: Exactly: it treats the rest of the line as a comment.

Comment: @Mico: Sorry, I didn't see your comments and thought that this is a general problem based on the question statement. Please feel free to reverse my edit. However, I suggest to clarify this in the question statement.

Comment: @jak123 - I think the OP's issue is very much connected to the front-end editing program, and actually has little to do with URLs *per se*.

Comment: @jak123: That might be something you need to suggest to the developers of TeXworks...

Comment: @Mark - You may believe that it's wrong for TeXworks to treat the remainder of a line that follows a `%` symbol as a comment, even though the symbol occurs in a URL string and is therefore not a comment character. It still seems very wrong, though, to "escape" such cases of the `%` symbol, as doing so will almost certainly mess up the work of all other editing programs, should the tex file ever be opened by an editor other than TeXworks. The correct way to fix your issue with TeXworks is to change one or more settings in TeXworks, *not* to modify the contents of a URL string.

Comment: fwiw, `Emacs/AUCTeX` highlights the argument to `\url` command as verbatim text, hence even a `%` inside does not cause the rest of the line to be font locked as a comment. How does `TeXworks` handle verbatim things like `\verb|foo|`? if it knows how do handle `\verb` then perhaps one can teach it how to handle `\url`.

Comment: Assuming no customization, it does nothing special for \verb.  I'm not sure if the syntax highlighting rules are flexible enough to handle this elegantly.